# Finding out names from Regular Expression using Python

Tags: python, regex

I have to find or extract names like `Aggarwal, Dr Rakesh Om` and `Aggarwal, Prof. Amita Rao` and using **regular expression** in **python** from a web page. 
I am learning regular expression.

I have use `[a-z]+,\s^Dr\s[a-z]+\s[a-z]+` for finding out names but can't worked for me.

Any suggesion..??

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think you need a regex like this:

```
"[A-Za-z]+\s*,\s*(Dr\.?|Prof\.?) [A-Za-z ]+"
```

With `g` modifier:

- **`[g modifier]`**: **g**lobal. All matches (don't return on first match)

[[Regex Demo]](https://regex101.com/r/rL9vS3/1)

or with adding `i` modifier you can make it more simpler:

```
"[a-z]+\s*,\s*(Dr\.?|Prof\.?) [a-z ]+"gi
```